# WordPress: Archive.php css broken sometimes (2 scenarios)?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Okay, on the website I display category's post on the author's posts for each blog post.

**Problem:** The when you click the **"Posted in [category]"** (under each post title) it goes to the category page, however, the CSS is broken.

**Confusion:** However if you click the author name (under each post) the CSS works. While author posts archive's CSS works, category's archive CSS doesn't work?!

**Additionally:** I have four main categories menu displayed on the blog which use the same code to link to categories AND it works! **However it doesn't show category URL link?**

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh6iR.jpg

**1. Category page under each blog post** **(CSS is being broken?)** LINK: http://radian3.com/category/personal-development/

```
                <p class="blog-info"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> | By <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author();?></a> | Posted In 
            <?php 
                $categories = get_the_category();
                $seperator = ", ";
                $output = '';
                if($categories) {
                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $output .= '<a href="'. get_category_link($category->term_id) .'">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $seperator;
                    }
                echo trim($output, $seperator);
                }

            ?></p>
```

**2. Menu categories in grey background (css works - yet uses same code however it doesn't show category url link). For e.x. click e.x. personal development category on blog.**

Link: http://radian3.com/blog/

```
        <div class="category">

            <?php 
                $categories = get_categories();
                foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                    if($cat->cat_name == 'PRODUCTIVITY') {
                     $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
                    }
                    break;               
                }
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>"><img class="category-icon" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/desktop/images/category-icon-1.jpg">
            <h3> PRODUCTIVITY</h3></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: the problem is the css is not loaded in these pages check it with f12 in browser

Comment: Are you talking about style.css? It is an empty file for a reason. Just there to be in the root directory so wordpress theme is installed apparently wordpress needs a style.css sheet in root. The actual css is default.css in css folder in directory

Comment: I see no problem on CSS, the structure of the page is different on both pages, that causes the elements to be displayed in distinct ways.

Comment: If the html is different  if is because how I'm getting the link to the categories (in php) the problem? Because I only have one archive.php so all archives should have the same structure @GustavoJantsch

Comment: I mean, if I use the element inspector I see that in the category page (category/personal-development/) we have the rule associated to the a: .blog-info a {color: grey;} because the blog-info class is associated to the "body" tag, in the blog we don't have the "blog-info" class associated anywhere. So it's not get_category_link() fault, but most probably how the header.php is rendering the HTML.